# segue to another view controller

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I've been trying to segue some labels across to another view controller but i can't seem to work it out.

my first view controller:

```
  import UIKit

class firstViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label6: UILabel!


var pickerLabels: [String!] {
    return [label1.text,label2.text,label3.text,label4.text,label5.text,label6.text]
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as thirdViewController
    controller.vc2Labels = pickerLabels //pickerLabels shows error


}

}
```

the labels in here are what I'm trying to segue but "pickerLabels" keeps coming up with an error

my second view controller:

```
   import UIKit
 class secondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


var vc2Labels: [String]!




func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component:Int) -> Int{
    return vc2Labels.count

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{

    return vc2Labels[row]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know your problem. You seem to be passing in an array of String into a string object.

Maybe you can alter your second view controller's variable to be:

```
var vc2Labels: [String]!
```

but I wouldn't recommend using implicit unwrapping of optional, since it allows a passing in of nil. You can declare an empty array like this.

```
var vc2Labels = [String]()
```

Hope this helps. More context would be helpful.

Comment: my second view controller seems to working fine now but in my first controller where i have " controller.vc2Labels = pickerLabels " the pickerLabels shows the error " 'String' is not identical to 'String' "

Comment: Which method did you use? Maybe I can try to duplicate the error in my playground so that I can help you further.

Comment: let optionalStrings: [String!] = ["Test","test2"] \n
let strings:[String!] = optionalStrings

Comment: ive edited the question hopefully its easier to see the problem

Comment: shouldn't your `let controller = segue.destinationViewController as thirdViewController` be `let controller = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController`

Comment: In your second view controller, try changing `var vc2Labels: [String]!` to `var vc2Labels: [String!]`

Comment: Yeah still getting that same error on the first controller with pickerLabels

Comment: Is there another way to segue a few labels across to another controller?

Comment: Nope. this is one of the better ways. You may want to consider not using the implicit unwrapping...